# What is the point of view when we say $\mathbb{R}^n$ has dimension $n$ in mathematical analysis?

Tags: dimension-theory-analysis

I know there are several different ways to define the dimension. What is the correct point of view to say that $\mathbb{R}^n$ has dimension $n$ in mathematical analysis?

Comment: Because it takes $n$ real numbers to uniquely specify a point, perhaps?

Comment: The analyst sees an $n$-dimensional manifold in it. But that boils down to the tangent space (again $\mathbb R^n$) being an $n$ dimensional vector space over the field $\mathbb R$.

Comment: @user132181 I can uniquely specify any point in $\mathbb{R}^{\left(10^{100}\right)}$ with a single real number.  _Analysis_ is the key here; the notion of continuity (as expressed via the tangent space in particular, as Hagen notes) is critical.